# HTTPS POST request (java) to a website (php), how to work with data from it?

Tags: java, php, security, ssl, https

This is more of a theoretical question, because at the moment I don't have a way to try it out on myself and I can not google the result somehow.

I will have https secured website and from my Java application I will be sending POST request to that site. I suppose that the request will be encrypted and POST data will not be in a format readable to human.

Do I get those data in unreadable format and it is up to me to decode it back in my php application? And if not, how it works then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTPS is a transport layer security,
which means it transparently encrypts/decripts your messages.

So you will have nothing to do to encode/decode the data.

What you will have to do is handling the SSL certificate correctly on establishing the HTTPS connection.